# Using a string value from excel vba to insert values in temp table in vba

Tags: sql, vba

I have already spent hours trying to make this work but this is not working. I hope someone here can help as I know most of you guys are much more knowledgeable and experienced when it comes to issues like these.
 I have a query in sql that needs to pick up data from a variable value defined as string in excel vba. Please see the sql code below. 'reg' is a string variable in vba and the values it holds are like (400),(410),(420),(601). For different regions these values will be different. Depending on what the user chooses, I want the values to be entered in this temp table.

I am using the following VBA

```
If Sheets("Filename").Range("i3").Value = "UK" Then 
      reg = Sheets("Filename").Range("k1").Value
ElseIf Sheets("Filename").Range("i3").Value = "Poland" Then 
     reg = Sheets("Filename").Range("k2").Value 
      oCMD.Parameters.Append oCMD.CreateParameter("reg", adLongVarChar, adParamInput, 255, reg)
```

`insert into @temp table values(@reg)`

As 'reg' is string in vba, I used @reg varchar(max) in sql. I have also tried to cast this to int trying it directly and also trying it through numeric but nothing has worked. Please see below.

`insert into @incWarehouses values(cast (cast (@reg as numeric(3,0)) as int))`

After using this, I get error message 'Error converting data type varchar to numeric'.

Also, I am using it like this in sql

@reg varchar(max)

declare @incWarehouses table (warehouse int)

insert into @incWarehouses values(cast (@reg as int))

Can anyone please help. Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Does `reg` have the brackets also?

Comment: Yes, reg shows it as it is as I have shown here. I have all these different strings in excel and reg picks up the one depending on the area chosen by user.

Comment: I don't think you can change `(000)` to a numeric value as it has brackets.  Try `mid(range("a1").value,2,3)` or  `mid(strValue,2,3)` as `reg` not sure from your post where the value is coming from

Comment: Thanks for quick reply again Nathan. All these values have been hardcoded in excel in different cells. So, like another cell has values (100),(110),(120),(200),(210),(215),(220),(225),(300),(310),(320),(600)

Comment: So try something like `mid(range("a1").value,2,3)`  Show the VBA code where you are building this SQL also if you can.

Comment: How are you populating reg, like `reg=range("a1").value` ???  Add the code to your post.

Comment: Public reg As String;    If Sheets("Filename").Range("i3").Value = "UK" Then
    reg = Sheets("Filename").Range("k1").Value
    ElseIf Sheets("Filename").Range("i3").Value = "Poland" Then
    reg = Sheets("Filename").Range("k2").Value                                              oCMD.Parameters.Append oCMD.CreateParameter("reg", adLongVarChar, adParamInput, 255, reg).            This is all in vba. Sorry, this window does not let me press enter for next line. Will show you the code for sql too.

Comment: try like `reg=replace(replace(Sheets("Filename").Range("k1").Value,"(",vbnullstring),")",vbnullstring)`  I cant see why it is not going into a VARCHAR(MAX) tho....

Comment: Tried this but didn't work. Same error. I have edited the query to include the sql too.

Comment: I am new to this so don't know much about how this works. It did not let me type more messages here yesterday. I kept trying and after few hours it did let me. I wanted to thank Nathan for trying to help me out. Not sure if this message will go or not.